# Exclude Weekends in Calculation

Tags: sql, vba, date, ms-access, weekday

I've been able to google some code that will remove weekends and holidays from calculations, I'm more concerned about removing the weekends.

The code below works perfectly, I think you can use WorkdayDiff(), but since this is based off DateAdd(), I think its going to be more complicated.

Basically I have a table that changes in length and I have it calculating due dates for me, again, I'm hoping for it to exclude weekends and holidays too if it's easy enough.  I really appreciate the help!

Main Goal: Subtract an extra 1 or two days if Saturday and/or Sunday are included in those dates.

```vb
Private Sub Command2_Click()
    DoCmd.SetWarnings False
    DoCmd.OpenQuery "Delete_A", acViewNormal, acEdit
    DoCmd.OpenQuery "Append_A", acViewNormal, acEdit
    DoCmd.OpenQuery "Append_Date", acViewNormal, acEdit

    Dim dbs As DAO.Database
    Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
    Dim dat As Date
    Set dbs = CurrentDb
    Set rst = dbs.OpenRecordset("select * from Table1 order by ID desc")
    With rst
        If Not .EOF Then
            .MoveFirst
            Do Until .EOF
                If Not IsNull(!Due_date) Then
                    dat = !Due_date
                Else
                    dat = DateAdd("d", -!Duration, dat)
                    .Edit
                    !Due_date = dat
                    .Update
                End If
                .MoveNext
            Loop
        End If
        .Close
    End With
    Set rst = Nothing
    Set dbs = Nothing


    DoCmd.OpenQuery "Delete_A_Exp", acViewNormal, acEdit
    DoCmd.OpenQuery "Append_A_Exp", acViewNormal, acEdit
    'DoCmd.RunMacro "A4_Export"
End Sub
```

Comment: is it intentional that if !Due_Date is not null, nothing happens with the record?

Comment: Yes, I'm filling in blank due dates, if they are there they should stay.

Comment: Subtracting holidays is pretty broad. If you have a table of holidays or a separate function to test if a day is a holiday, I can write up a function to subtract days ignoring those. What's a holiday is very dependent on your locale.

Comment: Yes, I can build a table of Holidays, can you write a function that would check the table and not include weekends?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following function to replace `DateAdd` to add or subtract a certain amount of workdays from a date.

```vb
Public Function WorkdayAdd(AmountOfDays As Long, InputDate As Date) As Date
    Dim increment As Long
    If AmountOfDays < 0 Then
        Increment = -1
    Else
        Increment = 1
    End If
    Do Until AmountOfDays = 0
         InputDate = InputDate + Increment
         If WeekDay(InputDate) <> vbSunday And WeekDay(InputDate)<> vbSaturday Then
             'Implement check if InputDate is a holiday here
              'If Not IsHoliday(InputDate) Then
                   AmountOfDays = AmountOfDays - Increment
              'End If
         End If
    Loop
    WorkdayAdd = InputDate
End Function
```

The `IsHoliday` function can be as simple as the following (Assumes there's a table named HolidayTable that contains a column, HolidayDate, that's filled with holidays).

```vb
Public Function IsHoliday(inputDate As Date) As Boolean
    TempVars!HolidayDate = Int(InputDate) 'No time part
    IsHoliday = DCount("HolidayDate", "HolidayTable", "HolidayDate = TempVars!HolidayDate") <> 0
    TempVars.Remove "HolidayDate"
End Function
```